# how to get records from data extension with matching user's resident id in lookup platform function

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, lookup, ssjs

I have a data extension with columns:

1. resident_id
2. preference_name
3. preference_value

here preference value is a boolean field.
I am using lookup function to get preference_value with matching user's resident id.
For example:
`var prefvalue = Platform.Function.Lookup('DE_name', 'preference_value', ['resident_id', 'preference_name'], ['user's resident id', 'some pref_name']);`
So, the question is what should i write in place of 'user's resident id' to get the row with matching resident id.

Comment: Well, you should use the user's resident_id to get a row with a matching resident_id - in case you are struggling to understand how lookups work, take a look here - it's about AMPscript, but the logic is the same: https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: I am trying to get the user's resident id dynamically. For that  var residentID = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");  this will work or not or var residentID = _subscriberkey;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just reference the `residentID` variable name in the lookup:

```
<script runat="server">

var residentID = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");

var prefvalue = Platform.Function.Lookup('DE_name', 'preference_value', ['resident_id', 'preference_name'], [residentID, 'some pref_name']);

Platform.Variable.SetValue("@prefvalue ", prefvalue);

</script>
<br>prefValue:%%=v(@prefValue)=%%
```

**Reference**:

- [Attribute.GetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_recipientGetValue.html)
- [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookup.html)
- [Variable.SetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformAMPscriptVariableSetValue.html)